# How to block arrow keys and the mouse in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard, mouse

I kinda started right now with Vim...
So, I'm using Janus and enjoying it. But it let me use the arrow keys. How can I block them?
I would also like to disable completely the mouse. (make it desappear if it's possible)

I really don't know where to put the changes and when I installed Janus it added some different dirs.

This is what i've done so far 
~/.vimrc.after/

```
noremap <Up> <Nop>
noremap <Down> <Nop>
noremap <Left> <Nop>
noremap <Right> <Nop>
set mouse= 
set ttymouse=
```

It blocked left and right arrows, but still lets me use up and down. Also the mouse.

Comment: Pro tip—just don’t use Janus. Youre better off crafting your own config.

Comment: Have you tried adding this config to `~/.vimrc.after` instead? That's what Janus recommends in order to override the settings that are provided by Janus itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone! 
And yes, I tried that, but didin't work for me

Comment: Hi, this worked! I updated the ~/.vimrc.after file with the code the other guy sent in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the arrow keys in ViM add the following lines to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
noremap <Up> <Nop>
noremap <Down> <Nop>
noremap <Left> <Nop>
noremap <Right> <Nop>
```

And for disable the mouse add these lines:

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Are you using ViM or Janus? In Janus i think that you have to add those lines in the `~/.vimrc.after` for tty and in `~/.gvimrc.after` for the GUI version.

Comment: Janus, and I added this code to ~/.vimrc.after. I don't know why but it seems to block only left and right keys, up and down are still working. Also the mouse

Comment: Wow.. so strange jaja. Could you paste in the question your `~/.vimrc.after` file please?

Comment: Sure, check it out

Comment: Did you add the config lines to the `~/.gvimrc.after` file? May you are launching the Janus on GUI mode?

Comment: I didn't. I'll try that now, but I guess I'm not using gvim.
I only launch through terminal

Comment: Hi, Did you test it with the ´~/.gvimrc.after` file?

Comment: Hey! Good news dude!!!
I don't know why or how, but this morning I openend Vim and TADAAAAM.... IT WORKED!

Comment: Jajaja, great!!